# Vim forgets cursor column when I move over a line that ends with a brace in insert mode

Tags: cursor-movement, insert-mode

Normally, when I use the up/down arrow keys to move between lines in insert mode (I'm using Vim wrong, I know), Vim remembers which column my cursor is in, so if I move to a line shorter than where my cursor is, then back to a longer line, the cursor pops right back to the same column. This is what I want and expect to happen, as well as what happens most of the time.

However, when I'm editing a Java sourcecode file and the last character in the shorter line is an opening or closing curly brace, square bracket, or parenthesis, Vim seems to forget entirely that the cursor was ever in any column other than the one immediately after the brace. The result is the I often find my cursor near the beginning of a line of code when I want and expect it to be at the end, so I have to $a to get back. Since this is Java, I have a lot of short lines ending with curly braces- so this is really annoying.

The weird part is that this only happens in insert mode- in normal mode, the arrows as well as j and k work fine. It's also weird that it only happens with those six grouping symbols- blank lines, lines with only whitespace, typical comments, and lines ending with semicolons cause no trouble in either mode.

It's not a bug in the Java plugin that I'm using- the exact same behavior happens in a .txt file.

I tried typing `:au CursorHold`, as instructed by one or two other answers to related questions, but it only prints `--- Auto-Commands ---` in purple text, and nothing to direct me to a bugged script.

Related: I recently upgraded my Apple-installed version of Vim 7.3 to Homebrew-installed Vim 7.4, which did not have this problem. I'm also on a Mac (and no, I'm not using GVim or MacVim).

Edit: I derped in writing the last paragraph above. Apple's Vim 7.3 install did not have this issue; Homebrew's Vim 7.4 did. Not that it matters now...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem using the Vim 7.3 that comes with OS X 10.9.

Comment: How about `:au CursorHoldI` or `:au CursorMovedI` ( both ending with uppercase i )?

Comment: Please show exact Vim version

Comment: I can't reproduce on vim 7.4.448

Comment: I can not reproduce with Vim 7.4 patches 1-622 using `vim -u NONE`. I would recommend you disable your plugins and vimrc customization until you find the culprit. protip: use a binary search to make it quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved! I tried typing :au CursorMovedI as tivn suggested in the comments, which said something about matchparen. I then typed :scriptnames, and lo and behold, it showed a matchparen.vim plugin installed in one of Homebrew's directories. CursorMovedI appeared in that file exactly once, in an augroup that looked like this:

```
augroup matchparen
  " Replace all matchparen autocommands
  autocmd! CursorMoved,CursorMovedI,WinEnter * call s:Highlight_Matching_Pair()
  if exists('##TextChanged')
    autocmd! TextChanged,TextChangedI * call s:Highlight_Matching_Pair()
  endif
augroup END
```

I then commented out the third line (the first autocmd! line) by prepending it with a quote, restarted Vim, and everything seems to be working fine.

If anything else breaks because of this, I'll know where to look.

Thanks to @tivn for pointing out :au CursorMovedI (that's a capital i at the end), which led me to this solution.

Update:
This fix appears to break the matching parenthesis highlighting; however, thanks to @tivn again, the source of the problem appears to be a bug in either the getcurpos() or setpos() functions called later in my matchparen.vim.

Both of these commands exist in if statements that appear to use these functions if the exist, or use the winsaveview() or winrestview(). Commenting out these if statements so that the win...view() functions are called no matter what fixes the cursor issue without also breaking the parenthesis highlighting.

As an example, here's the code on lines 88-99 of the unedited plugin file installed by Homebrew:

```
    let has_getcurpos = exists("*getcurpos")
    if has_getcurpos
      " getcurpos() is more efficient but doesn't exist before 7.4.313.
      let save_cursor = getcurpos()
    else
      let save_cursor = winsaveview()
    endif
```

Commenting out the inner if statement, except the line containing winsaveview(), results in this:

```
    let has_getcurpos = exists("*getcurpos")
 "   if has_getcurpos
 "     " getcurpos() is more efficient but doesn't exist before 7.4.313.
 "     let save_cursor = getcurpos()
 "   else
      let save_cursor = winsaveview()
 "   endif
```

Making this change, doing the same to lines 163-169, and uncommenting the autocmd! line above, seems to solve the cursor issue without causing any more.

Also, I'm using Vim 7.4.488. A pastebin of my matchparen.vim with these edits is available [here](http://pastebin.com/ZkJXadR5).

Comment: You should send Bram a bug report via the vim_use or vim_dev mailing list.

Comment: Good to know that. By comparing `matchparen.vim` between Vim 7.3 and 7.4, I am able to narrowing this to `save_cursor` variable used in the file. Rather than disabling autocmd, you can instead replace `let save_cursor = getcurpos()` and `call setpos('.', save_cursor)` with `let save_cursor = winsaveview()` and `call winrestview(save_cursor)` respectively. This way you don't loose the parenthesis pair highlighting.

Comment: I can't imagine why `getcurpos()` wouldn't work. In any case, a reproducable example of the problem should be posted to the vim-dev mailinglist, so Bram can fix the plugin.

Comment: Probably related to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/CMAGD6obzKo

Comment: That is a fixed by 7.4.578 (probably that's why I can't reproduce it), So please try with a newer Vim.